# JqGrid setGridParam is not working to assign datatype to json

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Datatype of grid is not changing to json using SetGridParam in button click funcation

I don't want to load the grid initially and only one button click the grid data should load. For this i set the datatype as "local" and changing the data type to json using SetGridParam. But this is not working and i am unable to figure it ot. Please help me.

```js
 $('#jQGrid').jqGrid({
        mtype: "POST",
        datatype:"local",
        url: "EmployeeDashBoard.aspx/GetEmpData",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },

        colNames: ['Employee', 'Age', 'Salary'],
        colModel: [

                    { name: "Employee", width: 70, index: 'Employee', sortable: false, resizable: false },
                    { name: "Age", width: 70, index: 'Age', sortable: false, resizable: false},
                    { name: "Salary", width: 70, index: 'Salary', sortable: false, resizable: false },


        ],
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
       beforeRequest: function () {
            var postData = $('#jQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', "postData");
            $.extend(postData, { "objFNFData": objFNFData });

        },

        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: function (obj) {
                return obj.d.FNFDataList;
            },
            total: function (obj) {
                return obj.d.Total;
            },
            records: function (obj) {
                return obj.d.Records
            }

        },

        loadComplete: function (obj) {

            if ($('#jQGrid').jqGrid.getGridParam('datatype') === "json") {
                $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide();


                if (obj.d.Total === 0) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    emptyMsgDiv.appendTo("#gview_jQGrid > .ui-jqgrid-bdiv");
                    $("[id$=btnExport]").hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();                        
                    $("#btnExport").attr("onclick", "openDownload()");
                    $("[id$=btnExport]").show();

                }
            }

        },

        rowNum: 20,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        sortable: false,            
        viewrecords: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100],
        pager: jQuery("#pager"),
        height: 'auto',
        caption: 'Employee Details',
        search: true
    });

     $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        $("#jQGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
    });
```

Comment: Your `var postData = ...` logic is in the wrong place and will be causing a syntax error. Similarly you appear to have an additional `}` after that block which is also a problem.

Comment: Please suggest where should include that postData logic

Comment: I have no idea as it's not clear what you're expecting it to do

Comment: i have updated the code..intially i defined datatype as local and trying to change it to json in  $("#btnSearch").click function. But data type is not chaning to json

Comment: How you determine that datatype is not changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a some code in loadComplete which is not correct. In order this to work it should be look like this:

```
   loadComplete: function (obj) {

        if ($('#jQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam','datatype') === "json") {
            $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide();


            if (obj.d.Total === 0) {
                $(this).hide();
                emptyMsgDiv.appendTo("#gview_jQGrid > .ui-jqgrid-bdiv");
                $("[id$=btnExport]").hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();                        
                $("#btnExport").attr("onclick", "openDownload()");
                $("[id$=btnExport]").show();

            }
        }

    }
```

I.e replace

```
if ($('#jQGrid').jqGrid.getGridParam('datatype') === "json") {
```

with

```
if ($('#jQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam','datatype') === "json") {
```

hope this will help